Has anyone else compared a Magloop to a Vertical?
I built a 3' diameter mag loop using rg8 and had a cap at the top. I compared it to a 17' vertical EF on my van and beside my house. Both times the Magloop did a good transmit signal into assorted Websdr's around the us, australia and hawaii. But it doesnt compare to a bigger antenna for receive. It just doesnt intercept as much magnetic waves as a bigger antenna. Has anyone else done receive tests with various Loops and Mag loops?

This is confusing - the loop should be somewhat weaker on transmit than the whip, but on receive I'd expect them to be about the same. Can you clarify a few things: Did you tune the loop each time, even when receiving? For best SWR or for strongest noise? And what sort of receiver were you using? Are you located in the US? (you could edit your Q to add information).

@tomnexus As far as I know, only in the US are antenna dimensions described in feet...

:) true. Also Canada and the UK, at least people of radio-ham age... I just wanted to clarify what sort of DX OP was talking about.

Let's find out... I am guessing K6 or K7 area.

I've used both and now almost exclusively use a vertical monopole. I'm mostly interested in DX and the lower takeoff angle and higher radiation efficiency of well designed vertical is a significant advantage. Magnetic loops generally have higher takeoff angles although the details vary with how you deploy it. So I think mag loops are better for 40/60/80m regional contacts rather than DX. However, my magloop transmissions on 20m were picked up in Europe (just not as strongly or reliably as with a vertical). Likewise my magloop on 40m was picked in Europe as well.
Mag loops have sharp nulls so you won't receive signals as much from those directions. Also, due to high takeoff angles, mag loops don't pick up DX signals as well as good verticals. On the other hand, verticals are not particularly good for low band NVIS because it radiates little into higher angles.
Another difference is avoiding man-made noise sources on the ground. Due to their low takeoff angles, Verticals pick up more of those noises, whereas magloops pick up less. Note, however, the DX signals and man-made noises come from the same low takeoff angles. Another advantage of magloop is the sharp nulls, which you can aim at a discrete noise source to minimize it. However, many nearby man-made noises are radiated by power lines or other long wires/structures (they appear distributed rather than discrete sources), and the sharp nulls may not be very effective in the urban environment. Overall, magloop as a receiver antenna is effective for low-band NVIS but not the best option for DX on any band.
When making a tuned loop antenna, I would build it bigger than typical, about 1/4 wavelength circumference. The radiation efficiency is much better than those smaller ones.
Also, the tuning capacitor at the bottom is usually better placement because the current maximum comes at a higher elevation. However, your loop is small, so the difference may be small (the current distribution is more uniform than bigger loops I used for better efficiency).

It just doesnt intercept as much magnetic waves as a bigger antenna.

Both vertical and loops interact with both electric and magnetic fields. But the effective area of the antenna that "absorbs" fields from the space is called "effective aperture," and that can be calculated. A bigger effective aperture is more advantageous in receiving or transmitting the signal, of course.
If there are any followup questions, please specify the band(s) of interest, what you aim (DX or regional), and your ground conditions/quality.
